# XSLT: for each problem

Tags: xslt

It supposed to be very simple, 
I want to limit my results in this for-each but also want to check a node.
For some reason it doesn't work combining them both in one statement?

I have a checkbox (recommended) which can be ticked to 'Yes'. 
When I remove the limit 5 in the for-each, it shows all the items that have recommended on 'Yes'. When I remove the 'recommended = 'Yes'' from the for-each test, I got the last items limited till 5. Putting them together results in nothing. They both don't work anymore. 
I want to filter them on Recommended 'Yes' and I want to limit them to 5.

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/resorts/entry[position() &lt; 2 and recommended = 'Yes']">
   <xsl:sort select="top-pick-order" case-order="upper-first"/>
       <a href="{$root}/koh-lipe-resorts/resort-view/{resort-name/@handle}">
           <div id="top-pick-item">
                 <div id="top-pick-text-short">
                  <h3 class="item-heading"><xsl:value-of select="resort-name"/></h3>
                  <p>   
                      <xsl:call-template name="truncate">
                          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="resort-description" mode="formatted"/>
                          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="110" />
                      </xsl:call-template>
                  </p>
                 </div>
           </div>
         </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the input XSLT (including both matching and non-matching nodes). Also describe what result you are getting and what you expect. As it strands this question doesn't contain enough information to help you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select=
>    "data/resorts/entry[position() &lt; 6
>   and
>     recommended = 'Yes']">
> ```

This will select all the `data/resorts/entry` elements among the first two, that also have a `recommended` attribute with value `'Yes'`.

**But you want**:

```
data/resorts/entry[recommended = 'Yes'][position() &lt; 6]
```

this expression first specifies *all* `data/resorts/entry` elements and then limits them only to those whose position *in the already obtained node-list* is less than 6.

**Remember**: The `position()` function is context-sensitive and it cannot be freely moved around an expression without changing its meaning!

Comment: Thanks Dimitre for the explanation and the solution! works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide some sample data yet I can only assume that `recommended` is an attribute of `<entry />`. In that case you need to have `@recommended` in your select statement:

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/resorts/entry[position() &lt; 2 and @recommended = 'Yes']">
```